# How many soldiers were present in DC for past presidents' inaugurations?

Tags: united-states, political-history

Recently it has been in the news that Biden's inauguration could feature more than 2,500, more than 5,000, more than 10,000, 20,000, 25,000, or even 30,000 national guardsmen in DC.

It's hard to contextualize these numbers because I'm not sure what is normal.

How many soldiers were present in DC for past inaugurations?

I am mainly interested in the more recent presidents (say, back to Clinton) as I think they will be most relevant in the comparison. I am also interested if there is any specific reason why a president has more or less than usual.

Comment: Normal would be none. Apart from a few officers and enlisted men being present during the ceremony.

Comment: @Jos Could you write that up in an answer? According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_inauguration_of_Barack_Obama) Obama's had 10,000 national guard, 8,000 police, 1,000 fbi, secret service snipers, 300 TSA, etc. Over 20,000 security personnel is obviously a far cry from "a few"! So what you are saying is very different to what I've seen elsewhere.

Comment: It doesn't give numbers, but [this](http://www.abrahamlincolnonline.org/lincoln/education/inaugural1.htm) says there was a large military presence at Lincoln's inauguration due to fears that those upset at his victory might react violently.  Presumably the general answer is that those in charge of security are going to try to match the perceived threat.

Comment: @GorttheRobot Is that to say they are ONLY deployed when there is a specific threat? Eg the 20,000 security at Obama's inauguration where to meet a specific perceived threat?

Comment: The wiki link you gave [covers that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_inauguration_of_Barack_Obama#Security)

Comment: @GorttheRobot It's a little confusing when you link to something I've already linked that contradicts what you said. Are you saying that now you have read the previous link you are revising your opinion to match? Sorry, the lack of context just makes your comment a bit confusing. Are you referring to something in particular in that section?

Comment: The wiki link says exactly what the rational for the security was.  " Army General Richard Rowe, head of the joint military task force for the Washington, D.C. area, explained that security forces had to stretch their imagination to anticipate previously unthinkable security threats, especially in light of the Mumbai attacks in India that occurred in November 2008."

Comment: Anyway, if I ever get free time, I'll work on an answer.  It seems that that TL;DR is that Clinton defined something called "National Security Events", and Bush decided they should apply to inaugurations, citing 9/11.  Since then, they've varied depending on what the various security services felt the threat level was.

Comment: @gbeeduljqa most of those would be present at all times guarding various buildings and persons, the 25000 Biden brought in were on top of that. If you want to be complete technically you'd have to add everyone with military rank working in the Pentagon and as congressional aides as well...